# Chrome Devtools closes while debugging website on Android device

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

`chrome://inspect/#devices` opens a devtools window, but about the time it finishes drawing itself, it closes.  No error messages

I'm trying to debug a website, not a native app.  Any ideas why it would open and tease me, then close when the mouse gets near the window?

- Linux:  Version 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit) OS:14.04 Ubuntu
- Android: Version 40.0.2214.109 OS: 4.1.2

More interesting details.  It works on other tabs, and if I use one of those tabs that is working, and paste in my URL, it closes the devtools

Comment: Seeing the same here, except on Win7 (and when inspecting a webpage served from localhost over http)

Comment: I had some reactjs code on the page, when I removed that, it stopped closing.  Not saying it is the fault of that react, but that did give me a chance to debug the rest of the page, when I put that code back it closes again.

Comment: We're not using React so it's probably correct not to fault it, but it could be triggered by some kind of script-error / security issue then.

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this yet? I agree that it seems to be script related. Some pages cause the bug while others do not.

Comment: Same problem on Mac (Yosemite). No solution found so far. I found this while searching, but it's non-conclusive for me: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing

Comment: What I noticed is that debugging e.g. google.com doesn't cause DevTools to close - it just doesn't work with my web application. I am using Angular and dozens of other JS stuff there, but not ReactJS, if anyone asked...

Comment: Same here, on a React-powered application. I can navigate and open/close tabs, but inspecting any (even google.com or simple pages) will make the inspect window appear and close itself before rendering.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en#remote-debugging-on-android-with-chrome-devtools), your desktop Chrome must be newer than your Android Chrome:

> Note: Remote debugging requires your version of desktop Chrome to be newer than the version of Chrome for Android on your device. For best results, use [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) (Mac/Windows) or the [Chrome Dev channel](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) release (Linux) on desktop.

For instance, you might install Chrome Canary/unstable or Chrome Beta on your computer. By using it instead, my inspector started working as expected. Currently, my Chrome Beta is v50 and the Android Chrome, v49.